# Can I name my tiny tower?

Tags: tiny-tower

I was wondering if I can name my tower like how you can rename your different floors.  Then when the bitizens talk about it in bit book they will refer to it by its name rather than just tiny tower.

Answer (score 5):

Based on experience in playing Tiny Tower, it is not possible to rename your tower.

I also did some research and it yielded no finds for renaming your tower.